# Rails - how to make join between these tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, join

I have these tables:

**users** - contains list of all users in the system

**cars** - list of all cars, there is a column **user_id**

**car_views** - for tracking how many people visit profile of a car. There are following columns:

```
- car_id
- ip
```

I am trying to fetch the information, how many people saw cars of a respective user within a time period. But my problem is, that I am not sure how can I fetch all views of cars from a respective user.

There would be a solution to put to the **car_views** table the column **user_id**, but it would be a duplication of information, or not?

Comment: Is car views meant to show who visited the car profile or just determine how many people have viewed it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this

```
user.cars.joins(:car_views).group('car_views.car_id').select('count(car_views.id) as count, car.name')
```

I'm not sure if this will work but you can give it a try

Comment: Awesome! I though you would need to make some changes to make it work. Good to know it worked